# Google Load Balancer refuses to save backend ports for GKE after node pool migration

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

I recently migrated my working deployment from a small node group to a large one using [this guide.](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/migrating-node-pool) Everything seems to be working fine, however the Google load balancer which is set up in front of my GKE cluster cannot seem to be fully updated to point to the new instance group.

I have configured all backends to the new node pool perfectly fine, however 2 out of the 3 backends have lost the correct port. I go to edit the load balancer and put the new ports, but whenever I apply the changes, the load balancer configuration does not update. 2 of the 3 backends do not seem to be able to have a port assigned to them. The backend type is "instance groups"

Answer (score 0):

I have just fixed this problem by using the 'backends' tab, clicking the backend I want to add the port to, then setting it and saving it there in what I assume is the legacy page for configuring backends.

I believe this is an issue with the all-in-one 'edit load balancer' page found by clicking the pencil "edit" button at the top of the page while viewing a load balancer.